# Converting python list of delimited items in to a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list like this where items are separated by ":".

```
   x=['john:42:engineer',
      'michael:29:doctor']
```

Is there an way to change this in to a data frame like below by defining columns Name, Age and Occupation?

```
    Name    Age Occupation
0   john    42  engineer
1   michael 29  doctor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will do

```
df = pd.Series(x).str.split(':',expand=True)
df.columns = ['Name','Age', 'Occupation']
df
Out[172]: 
      Name Age Occupation
0     john  42   engineer
1  michael  29     doctor
```

Comment: this is nice :).  This will likely be more performant than putting a comprehension in the constructor?

Comment: @anon01 I think so ~

Comment: looks like performance is ~ the same.  Compared execution time of this with Quang Hoang's answer using `x = x*1000000`.  Both took ~4 sec on my machine

Comment: @anon01 ah , ok ~ :-)

Comment: @anon01 Most of string operations in pandas/numpy are not vectorized. Converting to pandas series, if anything, only creates extra overhead.

Comment: @BEN_YO not my down vote either. Your answer is somewhat more readable than mine. List comprehension is not really reader-friendly to many people.

Comment: @QuangHoang no worry , just some random people ~ :-) I figure it out, that is why I upvote your answer and remove my comment ~~

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `split`:

```
pd.DataFrame([y.split(':') for y in x], columns = ['Name','Age', 'Occupation'])
```

Output:

```
      Name Age Occupation
0     john  42   engineer
1  michael  29     doctor
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best approach, but...

```
x = ['john:42:engineer', 'michael:29:doctor']
x = [i.split(':') for i in x]
pd.DataFrame({'name': [i[0] for i in x], 'age': [i[2] for i in x], 'occupation': [i[1] for i in x]})

Output:

    name    age occupation
0   john    42  engineer
1   michael 29  doctor
```

Comment: @Quang Hoang's is better